# C++ inheritance, sending a pointer to base class

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, constructor, superclass

I have a `ninjaCreep` class that is derived from a class `Creep`. I want to pass the pointer that I have acquired through the parameters of the derived class to the base class' constructor however I am getting this error:

> ../ninjacreep.cpp|4|error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is >‘Ogre::SceneManager’)|

The code:

```
ninjaCreep::ninjaCreep(Ogre::SceneManager& sceneManager, int x, int y, int z, std::string id)
        : Creep(*sceneManager, x, y ,z, id) //line 4
{
    //ctor
}
```

I have never passed a pointer to a base class before, so I think the error lies somewhere there?

Creep constructor has the same parameters as `ninjaCreep`:

```
Creep(Ogre::SceneManager& sceneManager, int x, int y, int z, std::string id);
```

Comment: "I have never passed a pointer to a base class before" - you're not passing one now either. That is a reference parameter; not a pointer. The compiler is complaining because `*sceneManager` is trying to apply `operator *` to something that isn't a pointer and there is no overload to allow it. Lose the `*`.

Comment: You're right, my mistake (you would imagine I stop making pointer mistakes after using them for about a year now...)

Comment: Or *not* using them in this case. =P

Comment: My guess would be: `: Creep(*sceneManager, x, y ,z, id) //line 4` may need to be `: Creep(&sceneManager, x, y ,z, id) //line 4`. If you want a pointer you need to take the address using `&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use the parameters as they originally are:

```
ninjaCreep::ninjaCreep(Ogre::SceneManager& sceneManager, int x, int y, int z, std::string id)
        : Creep(sceneManager, x, y ,z, id) //line 4 no "*"
{
    //ctor
}
```

`sceneManager` is not a pointer: it's a **reference** to an object of type `SceneManger`.  It is to be used a normal `SceneManager` object, without any dereference.

**Important note:**

`&` can be part of a type declaration:

```
int a 
int &i=a ;  // i is a reference.  you can then use i and a interchangeably
```

It is not be confused with the address taking operator:

```
int a; 
int *pa = &a;  // pa is a pointer to a.  It contains the adress of a. 
               // You can then use *pa and a interchangeably
               // until another address is assigned to pa.
```